# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasTouchScreen

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, automation

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestPlan {
    private static final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ChromeDriver location set up in Utils class
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Utils.CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION);
    }

    @Test(testName = "Submit a WebForm")
    public static void submitForm(){
        driver.get(Utils.BASE_URL);
        WebForm webForm = new WebForm(driver);
        webForm.enterFirstName();
        webForm.enterLastName();
        webForm.pressSubmitButton();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public static void cleanUp(){
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I can run this test please help me, having an error on this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasTouchScreen
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at TestPlan.<clinit>(TestPlan.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: can you please mention which selenium version you're using

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same issue after upgrading to selenium 4.5.3 and fixed it by adding the below dependencies for chrome and firefox drivers.

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```